# RegEx: Getting a character with a special follower without the follower?

Tags: regex

Good Morning :)

Imagine this string:

```
-2x^3+3x^2-4x+1.5
```

I want to extract the 'x', which is not followed by a '^'.
I tried `(x)[^\^]`, but this captures the '+' behind the last 'x', too. How can I extract just the 'x', without the following '+'? Is this even possible or do I have to do it manually in the rest of the program code?

Greetings!

Comment: Technically, your regex ``matches`` but doesn't ``capture`` the "+" sign. Only what's inside parentheses is captured. Depending on what language/engine you are using, you can distinguish between the two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead as follows:

```
x(?!\^)
```

The backslash is to escape the caret so it doesn't match the beginning of a line but a literal caret.

This expression will match any `x` which is not followed by the character `^`.

Comment: +1 This is better than my alternative for matching the `x` at the end of the string.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks, but you removed the `|$` part in your answer? :( It would work just as well if you keep it; just a little longer, because it won't be matching in `3x^2+2x` as it is now :(

Comment: I've added it back just as an alternative just for completeness. It *may* be the case that OP just wants to match it in the middle of the string, though I doubt it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Mhm. Better be safer in such cases :)

Comment: thank you, works as intended :) @p.s.w.g yes, it might appear everywhere in a string ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead assertion, if your regular expression engine supports it:

```
(x)(?=[^^])
```

This will match any `x` followed by any character other than `^`, but it will not capture the following character.

If you'd also like to match `x` at the end of the string you could use this:

```
(x)(?=[^^]|$)
```

This will match any `x` followed by any character other than `^` or the end of the string, but it will not capture the following character, if it exists. Although [Jerry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664924/1715579) is a bit more elegant in that case.